# Customizing a class file

Tags: document-classes

I want to extend the `exam` class and create a new class called `homework.cls`. I want the default options to be **12pt** and **times**, but I get **10pt**. Here's the code I've written:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{wc-homework}[2017/01/01 My Custom Homework class]

\LoadClass[12point, times]{exam}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{exam}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fullpage, cleveref, amsfonts, amsmath, tikz, setspace, hyperref,
  graphicx, wrapfig, parskip, pgfplots, times, amssymb}

\newcommand*{\@hwtitle}{}
\newcommand*{\hwtitle}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@hwtitle}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\makehwtitle}{%
  \setlength\FrameRule{1.5pt}

  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}}

  \begin{framed}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{large}
  \textbf{My Math Class}\\
  \textbf{Practice Exercises}\\
  \end{large}
  \smallskip
  \textbf{\textit{\@hwtitle}}
  \smallskip
  \end{center}
  \hrule height 1.7pt

  Some boring boilerplate instructions.
  \smallskip

  More instructions.
  \end{framed}
}
\endinput
```

The main problem is that the framed section is too narrow, and the font size is not big enough. It's like I lose everything I set up above the `\makehwtitle` command.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I do not see either `12point` or `times` in the allowed option of `exam` (if you mean the exam class in texlive).

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, thanks for pointing this out. When I pass `12pt` to `exam` it certainly seems to work. Fixing this mistake fixed part of my problem. Placing the code correctly helped, and I've updated the code above.

I still don't get the right (same) font as if I just use the same options with the `exam` class. I also get a smaller width framed environment than I do with the normal `exam`. Any thoughts on that?

And thanks again for help so far!

Comment: please _don't_  fix code in questions, the site archives the question forever and it makes answers very hard to understand if they are referring to code that has changed.

Comment: I've un-fixed the code. Hopefully that doesn't compound the problem!

Comment: In this code you are using `RequirePackage{times}` (which isn't really a recommended package tehse days0 to get times fonts, yiu haven't said how you call exam, but obviously this would change the fonts, just don't load any font package if you want to get teh default exam class behaviour, similarly you have loaded fullpage package which will change the page size as normally used by exam class.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It's clear that I know just enough to be dangerous. I'm going to have to learn more about this before I do anything more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see either `12point` or `times` in the allowed option of exam (if you mean the exam class in texlive) presumably you meant `12pt` for the first

Also these lines

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{exam}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

need to be *before*

```
\LoadClass{exam}
```

as there is no point passing options to a class *after* it has been loaded.

to get times-like fonts perhaps you want something like

```
\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```